# How to split a string at each character

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am using ASP.NET Web Pages to create a project in which I am assigned to place each character of the user's (customer's) name in each seperate input block.

For that I am getting the value from the Sql Server CE Database and then I am trying to convert it into an array of **one character for each input**. I have tried the following code for that

```
var form_data = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Form_Data WHERE Form_Id =@0", form_id);
var name_emp = form_data.Name_Emig;
if(name_emp != null) {
    name_emp = name_emp.ToString().Split('');
}
```

It generates the following Compiler error:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eb78ww7(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eb78ww7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (Compiler error: CS1011)

Which means that the character cannot be initialized by an empty value. I want to convert that value in one character each array.

The name is as: **Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan**. So, in each input it would be placed inside the value of it. But the code I am using isn't working. Any suggestion to split the string at each character, so the result would be

```
{'A', 'F', 'Z', 'A', 'A', 'L' ...}
```

It doesn't matter whether result is Capital case or lower case. I will convert it to the desired one later.

Comment: Just use String.ToCharArray() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am trying to get the characters in the name. So that they can be written in order of `one character in each input`. Like a legal submission form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `ToCharArray()`.

So your code would be this:

```
var form_data = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Form_Data WHERE Form_Id =@0", form_id);
var name_emp = form_data.Name_Emig;
if(name_emp != null) {
    name_emp = name_emp.ToCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to iterate with each item :

```
string yourString = "test";

foreach(var character in yourString)
{
 // do something with each character.
}
```

Or this to get all characters in a `char[]`

```
char[] characters = yourstring.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Wow! I never thought of that one...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `name_emp.ToArray()`. A string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so `ToArray` will return an array of the `char`.

Edit:
Actually I suppose `ToCharArray` is better in this case...